How to state that a function has a certain trend in a limit
Assuming we have a function $f(r)$ that has the following limit
$$ \lim_{r\to0} f(r) = \frac{5}{3 r^2} \,.$$
What is the correct symbol to express that the denominator goes like $r^2$?
Is the following correct:
$$f(r) \overset{r\to 0}{\propto} \frac{1}{r^2} \,.$$
What about this
$$f(r) \overset{r\to 0}{\approx} \frac{1}{r^2} \,.$$

I think this is question is better suited to mathematics SE.

Beyond that, the first equation you wrote does not make sense in the standard sense of a limit, since it still contains $r$ on the right hand side. Also I think you meant the denominator, instead of the numerator.

@MartinC. yes sorry it was a typo I meant the denominator

$\lim_{r\to0}f(r)\propto r^{-2}$; call it a day.

@KyleKanos $f(r) \overset{r\to 0}{\propto} r^{-2}$ would also be acceptable?

Words are best: "Near $0$, $f(r) \propto 1/r^2$". The $r \to 0$ over the proportionality would be weird but understood. Inventing strange notation distracts the reader.

As written, $\lim_{r\to0} f(r) = \frac5{3r^2}$ doesn't make sense (neither would $\lim_{r\to0} f(r) = r^2$: the left-hand side is a number while the right-hand side is a function). Presumably what is intended is
$$
\lim_{r\to0} \frac{f(r)}{5/3r^2} = 1.
$$
A common notation to show that these two functions grow at the same rate in this sense is
$$
f(r) \sim \frac5{3r^2} \text{ as } r\to0.
$$
It is also correct to write
$$
f(r) \propto \frac1{r^2} \text{ as } r\to0
$$
when the constant coefficient isn't important.
In both cases, it is much clearer to write "as $r\to0$" as part of the sentence than to try to stack a bunch of notation on top of itself. The goal of writing math is clear communication, not minimizing the number of words. (Depending on the context of the surrounding sentences, one could even omit "as $r\to0$" entirely if the meaning will already be clear to the reader.)
